# Plot a line with multiple markershapes

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Trying to plot a line where each point has its own markershape, I tried:

```
using Plots
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = [2, 3, 2.4]
markers = [:x, :hexagon, :none]
plot(xs, ys, markershape=markers)
```

But that gives the following, which only has xs as markers:
[image]

I also tried 1x3 array but no luck.

Comment: I tried this (Julia 1.4, Qt backend) and it worked as it should.  Perhaps some resource in the backed on your machine is failing to load?

Comment: Seems a Plots version issue https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/2876

Comment: It's working for me as I mentioned in the issue comment https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/2876#issuecomment-820380751. Could you try again and maybe close this if it's been solved?